# VBA Error while updating pivot table filter to show current month's data only

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

This seems like a simple problem, but I've spent hours failing to solve... 
I'd like to have my pivot table update an existing filter to include all dates this month. I regularly update the data source and this source includes data from year to date. In my pivot table, I only want to see this month's data. So I wrote this:

```
Dim pvtAOL As PivotTable
Set pvtAOL = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

pvtAOL.TableRange1.Activate
pvtAOL.RefreshTable
pvtAOL.PivotFields("Date").ClearAllFilters
pvtAOL.PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters.Add FilterType:=xlAllDatesInPeriodJuly
```

If I comment out the last line, everything works. If I try to run it with the last line included, I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '448':Named argument not found
```

Open to other fixes / corrections if you see them as I'm new to VBA. thx!

Comment: what about `xlDateThisMonth`? Also does excel recognize the `Date` PivotField as an actual Date value? [Find enumeration here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241427(v=office.12).aspx) .. if it helps.

Comment: I am uploading a file named [01-08-14.xlsm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xe2ipyhlad4vggm/01_08_14.xlsm?dl=0). This is for a date period range which can be modified for your purpose suitably.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, xlDateThisMonth gives the same error. I've visited the enumeration page but not really sure how to use it to solve this problem. I've wondered if I need to stipulate the date format in someway? the raw data uses mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: I am finding [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838592.aspx) a bit confusing.  It says the "Name" of the parameter is `Type`, but the examples use `FilterType`.  When you record a macro doing a similar thing, the created code uses `Type`.  Maybe they are synonyms, but it might be worth trying to change FilterType to Type.

Comment: @YowE3K, I noticed the same thing. Most-all the examples of similar code I've found use `FilterType` and using `Type` gives me a different error: `Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error`

Comment: @KentSanner - I just tried a small piece of code, and using FilterType did give the OP's error, and using Type did work.  I think I might post that as an answer.  (I get the 1004 error if I tried adding a Filter when one already existed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838592.aspx) is a bit confusing. It says the "Name" of the parameter is `Type`, but the examples use `FilterType`.

When you record a macro doing a similar thing, the created code uses `Type`.

I have done some testing and get the same error as the OP when using `FilterType` but using `Type` works.

I suggest changing your code from

```
pvtAOL.PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters.Add FilterType:=xlAllDatesInPeriodJuly
```

to

```
pvtAOL.PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlAllDatesInPeriodJuly
```

To clear existing filters from the "Date" field so that you can add a new filter, use

```
pvtAOL.PivotFields("Date").ClearLabelFilters
```

(Or use .ClearAllFilters if you prefer.)

Comment: Hmm, this did get rid of the error and code runs to completion, but it doesn't actually apply the filter... Also, updating the OP because this is an already active pivot table with an already active `Date` filter. So really, I'm trying to update the filter not `.Add`

Comment: @KentSanner - I've updated the answer to show how to use `.ClearLabelFilters`.